# Inline variable substitution not working for start time parameter in network analysis using ArcMap ModelBuilder

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, network-analyst, dynamic, variables

I stumbled over a problem in the ArcMap ModelBuilder setting an inline variable substitution for the parameter `Start Time` necessary to determine the starting point in time for a network analysis.

I am trying to iterate over rows in a table, which give me details for a trip to be used in a network analysis (`Route analysis`), including the origin and destination points as well as the starting point in time for when the trip is being made.

I get the data for the starting time out of the respective field in the table via `Get Field Value`. I then try to implement the value, named `START`, as inline variable substitution for the parameter `Start Time` in the `Route Analysis` tool using `%START%`. But it doesn't work as planned because the parameter does not fill blue and input is gone as soon as I open the parameter again.

The format of the starting time data is `dd.mm.yyy hh:mm:ss`. I tried formatting it as `date`, `string` or `time` format, but it won't work.

Is it even possible to dynamically change the value of a network analysis start time based on iterating through a data table containing various start times?

Comment: Can you please share a picture of your model or a sample?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.

Inline variable substitution is not necessary. If the data format is set right, one can just connect the elements directly in the ModelBuilder.